# how to hook a callback to click event of star rating control

Tags: events, jquery-plugins

I am using jQuery star rating control found at http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/#tab-Overview . I am using 5 stars, each star having a particular value from 1 to 5.  The control is getting displayed and behaving properly. However, I have a requirement of getting the value of the star clicked, immediately after a star is clicked. I do not know how to do it.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After analyzing the structure of the markup generated by the rating control, I added the following code in the document ready function.

```
    $('div.star').live('click', function() {
        var value = $('a', this).html().trim();


        var ratingName = $(this).parent().next('input[type="radio"]').attr('name');

        alert('rating for ' + ratingName ' is ' + value);
    });
```

This is working fine, but is very indirect. I don't know more direct solution.

Answer (score 0):

The stars are basically using the radio buttons behind the scenes and have the class `star`, Try this:

```
$(function(){
  $('.star').live('click', function(){
     alert($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Comment: This did not help me. In fact the event itself did not fire.

Comment: @mohang: I have modified my answer, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

In a project we were using that same plugin and had to move out from it because it was really slow when having a lot of star ratings in the same page (it generates a lot of dom elements for each input element).
We ended up implementing the css only tecnique [seen here](http://www.search-this.com/2007/05/23/css-the-star-matrix-pre-loaded/), it's way faster (but It obviously loose some options like the "partial star" rating)

Comment: Yes, I have also experienced the same in our project. we are using this only in places where selection is required. For display purposes, we are using a simple CSS technique using boxes.